# iOS storyboard based application crashed on device with error exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on iphone application which is having 5-6 navigation screen and having push notification in it.But my application is getting crashed while navigating randomly with error

```
exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and see where it stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation fault occur when you try to access reference of memory which doesn't exist anymore, In case of iOS your code is accessing a object or variable which released after you used and then you  are again using it but that has been released by reference counter. Try to check reference in your code.

First set properties to `strong` reference type which are being used throughout the app. Memory alloc and dealloc can be tracked by running application with Instruments in Xcode. Also you can use breakpoints in flow of application so that you can know in your code exactly from where this app is crashing and which objects or variables were being used that time.

Comment: The memory doesn't exist anymore?! :)

Comment: I mean reference to memory location :)

Comment: but how to track the location of referred object that is not in memory currently on device,it is crashing in random scenarios

Comment: I have already used instruments for leaks and memory allocation but haven't discovered any leaks.In addition to that I am using arc ,so there is no case where I released the references manually.Can you help me how to track the object reference for the same.As I am having push notification in my application I can test my code or track the crash only using ipa . Please reply asap.Thanks in advance

Comment: I can test ipa only on device, I cant run the project through xcode as I am having push notification in my app.So how can I test using breakpoints.Also I have added NSLogs in all methods.But the app is crashing randomly and crashes occurred after the printing last line of every method.So it is getting difficult to detect the crash.

Comment: Can You please help I am also getting the same problem.. I am doing pushing and poping the various view  and then randomly getting crash with the same reason above, as I am using arc in my project.. Please help..what to do to ressolve it.?